# System Clock vs. Hardware Clock (RTC) in embedded systems

Tags: linux, hardware, embedded, clock, cpu-frequency

The system clock is maintained by the kernel, whereas the hardware clock is maintained by the Real Time Clock (RTC).

1. Do both clock run at same frequency?
2. Are both independent of each other?
3. What happens when Real time clock fails? Does it affect the system clock?

Can anyone let me know the difference between both the clocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *both clock run at same frequency?*

   Usually there are two clocks inside a computer/device/system. One is powered from a battery (usually a CR2032, could be the main battery or even a supercap in an embedded system) and runs from an dedicated chip. The other one is driven by the CPU clock source (with its own quartz crystal).

   One usually runs from a 32.768kHz crystal. The other one from a CPU crystal Mhz or GHz range. There is a lot of variation as there are a lot of CPU models.
2. *both are independent of each other?*

   Yes, most of the time. But one could adjust the other (on embedded linux you typically have the `hwclock` command with options `-r` or `-w`). The CPU clock is set by the chip clock on boot (the CPU has no idea of what time it is when booting). For a system in a network, the CPU clock might find better time value from the network via the NTP (Network Time Protocol) and then adjust or correct the value inside the clock chip.
3. *what happens when Real time clock fails does it affect system clock?*

   Yes, sure, if the battery runs out, for example, the computer boots up with a completely out of wack idea of real time But, nowadays, most of the systems have some network connectivity and update their concept of real time pretty soon after boot via the NTP protocol.
4. *can anyone let me know the difference between both the clocks.*

   As said above, one clock source is a chip, the other is the CPU.

Note that I have avoided calling the chip clock the RTC clock as there are internal values on the CPU also called RTC. But yes that is the common name for it.

Related:

- [Real-Time -Clock](https://iqramali.medium.com/role-of-rtc-real-time-clock-in-embedded-devices-35dbd2e8f9e7)
- [Kernel reference](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/rtc.html)
- [Red-Hat reference](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18627)

Answer (score 2):

> both clock run at same frequency?

**Not necessarily but generally not.**
Hardware clocks (there can be many, particularly on numa and embedded systems) are oscillators beating at some frequency depending on a [crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator_frequencies) and offering dedicated set of dividers. These are **clock-sources.**

The *system clock* is not a real clock-source but it will depend on a given hardware clock that **can** be some RTC.
If having several RTC, the one the system will know as RTC can be select thanks to udev rules.

---

> both are independent of each other?

**Generally not but… possibly.**
The kernel is offered different hardware clock sources, most often :
The Time Stamp Counter (TSC), the High Precision Event Timer (HPET), the ACPI Power Management Timer (ACPI_PM), the Programmable Interval Timer (PIT), and the Real Time Clock (RTC).

You can list those made available on your system cat-ing `/sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource`, you can select the preferred system clocksource echoi-ing to `/sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource`

So you **can** actually force your system clock to depend on the RTC.

This is **generally** not advisable since the RTC is costly to read and generally get a lower resolution compared to clock sources based on cpu's frequency.
It is therefore sub-optimal for use with a real-time kernel.

**The linux-kernel preferred clock-source is the TSC**. (The system will rely on it when starting the boot process) my bootlog tells :

> clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc-early

However, on tickless systems, this source is definitely unstable and cannot be reliably used. In which case, when available, the kernel will switch to HPET, the second one to be preferred.

> tsc: Marking TSC unstable due to TSC halts in idle
>
> clocksource: Switched to clocksource hpet

---

> what happens when Real time clock fails does it affect system clock

At run time, nothing wrong should happen (from a kernel standpoint) as long as the RTC in not the preferred clock source.
**Of course, since watchdogs are generally based on RTCs, their effectiveness become… unpredictable, which can indeed be a problem on embedded systems.**
At reboot time, your system is likely to start with some unpredictable date and time which **can** possibly be a concern for misc logs management and cron decisions.

Comment: One clock comes from a clock chip (with a 32.768kHz crystal and a battery for system power off) [for example](https://www5-stage.epsondevice.com/en/products/rtc/rx8111ce.html) and all the other clocks (including the one you call RTC) come from the CPU clock. The clock chip sets the CPU clock on boot, then the CPU keeps its own idea of time.

Comment: @QuartzCristal : "all the other clocks (including…) come from the CPU clock". I do think this is wrong. Only the TSC and HPET clocksources are based on cpu clock. ACPI_PM, PIT and RTCs are in no way based on the cpu clock.

Comment: Watchdogs generally based on RTCs? All microcontrollers I worked with had a watchdog controller relying on the internal clock, while I don't remember any linux RTC driver that allows to access the watchdog of the RTC (if it has one at all).

Comment: @Philippos : My statement if possibly ill-written. I mean that if you get some watchdog device (with of course some embedded hardware clock) you can actually select this hardware clock as being the system's RTC. I've done that with Toradex modules.

Comment: "on tickless systems, this source is definitely unstable and cannot be reliably used" is not true in general. At least on x86_64, any non-ancient CPU has a TSC that keeps counting even in sleep states, so you won't see the "TSC halts in idle" message in the kernel log on most current machines and TSC will be used as the main clocksource. I guess the situation might be different on some (smaller) embedded platforms. (Tickless or not doesn't matter, the TSC is not based on timer interrupts, it's a free-running hardware counter.)

Comment: @TooTea : Interesting indeed. I'am old school running all sorts of… old hardware :-) I stay nevertheless curious of novelties… could you please give more info regarding x86_64 cpu generations from which started that (for me impressive) improvement from… my core II. I will amend my answer.

Comment: What kind of embedded system uses an MC146818 with 50 µA standby current as RTC? A board computer in a truck, maybe. Typical RTCs need less than 1 µA, and that's what you usually prefer in embedded systems. This whole answer seems to mainly target PCs and servers.

Comment: @MC68020 I guessed as much from your username here :-) This CPU feature is visible in `/proc/cpuinfo` on Linux as `nonstop_tsc` and it's based on a CPUID flag. Off the top of my head, it's been generally available on Intel since Nehalem (original Core i3/5/7) and on AMD since K10 (original Phenom, Athlon II), so 2008-ish. There might be some exceptions in both directions, you would have to browse the docs or google for cpuinfo listings from old CPUs. And when it comes to embedded, newer Intel Atoms (e.g. Cloverview) even keep the TSC running when suspended to RAM and ARM has something similar.

Comment: @Philippos : I honestly cannot remember the RTC chip running on my home-made live-performing DAW. But… frankly ! When you have a 5ma current loop to power (for the midi hardware stuff)… 50µa ? who cares ? OK ! This is not an eco-friendly DAW ! But it is a truely embedded system.

Answer (score 0):

The RTC is usually intended to maintain the time across reboots, which is why it has its own battery. This lets the system have an accurate-ish idea of the time during early bootup, before NTP can sync time against "the internet". If the RTC fails, the early bootup timestamps will be nonsense, usually Jan 1, 1970 UTC, the start of the Unix Epoch; the initial value is 0.

One thing to note: unix-likes store UTC in the RTC. Windows (yes, there are embedded version of Windows) stores local time in the RTC. Switching back and forth can cause confusion and dual booting is a mess unless the unix-like has special handling (which Linux does IIRC; some kernel parameter during boot).

Comment: Or windows could be told to use UTC times in the RTC, which windows is perfectly able to do unless they removed that capacity in latest versions :-(.